# How to get value of FieldObject in Visual Studio Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am loading a value from my SQL table as a FieldObject to the [Crystal Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGPPT.png).

Here in the picture I am trying to create a dynamic text that changes with the Field Object(there is no property). The way I try to do is:

In every page, Field Object will change and I will write some code to process the value and update the dynamic text. But the problem is I can't reach the value of FieldObject. I can't get the text like this:

```
(report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Field Object"] as TextObject).Text
```

summary of the code is like:

```
                case 0:
                    if (something == somethingElse)
                        (report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Dynamic Text"] as  TextObject).Text = "foo1";
                    else
                        (report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Dynamic Text"] as TextObject).Text = "foo2";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (FieldObject != null && FieldObject != string.Empty) 
                    {
                        //some sql query execution

                            RunQuery("some query WHERE ID = @FieldObject");

                            {
                              //set dynamic text with result of RunQuery  
                              ...something  
                            }
                        }
```

And even if I achieve this I don't exactly know how to change the "dynamic text" for each page. Any idea?
Thank you for reading.

Note: I think It wont be possible to do this inside crystal reports with formula since I am using it in c# classes

Comment: i would join a table with your querey as subquery and add it to the table as a new field, evrething else seem t be too much trouble

Comment: But it gets also complicated :D

Comment: no it is quite simple sql joinig subqueries

Comment: Yes I know that but in this case I need to use some variables that I used in my functions. Because name is not only decided by database. It is also decided by user inputs.

Comment: You have user inputs after generating the report? you concept is hard to grasp, you want tp manipulate the report, so you must have the user input already, so you can make a datasource. dynamic content is tricky